# Change in Diffie-Hellman

Tags: diffie-hellman

In the Diffie-Hellman protocol, each participant selects a secret number $x$ and sends the other participant $α^x\bmod q$ for some public number $α$.

What would happen if the participants sent each other $x\,α\bmod q$ for some public number $α$ instead?

Give at least one method Alice and Bob could use to agree on a key. Can Eve break your system without finding the secret numbers? Can Eve find the secret numbers?

I figure out that it is vulnerable to use $x$ instead of $α$ because Eve can find $x$ by using Fermat theorem. But I can't find system in which both will agree. Please indicate the system that they might use here.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Voting to close

Comment: We do allow homework *related* questions, sahil, but normally we only give hints to homework questions and only if enough effort is shown to solve it yourself. If you edit in your thoughts the question might be reopened - if just for some hints in the comment section.

Comment: As the question has been edited to include some effort from the asker, I've reopened so that other users may comment and provide hints.